# Android DDMS Fails To Establish Loopback Thread

Tags: android-emulator, ddms

I have tried in both Eclipse ADT and the ddms.bat that comes with the android sdk. Both have the same result: *"Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection"*.

However, if I boot my computer in safe-mode, it works just fine. Obviously this means the issue is with some third party service or driver on my computer.

So I went through and stopped every non-critical service on my computer in normal mode and still the ddms returns the error.

**How do I identify what is causing the issue?**

*Computer Details:

Windows 7 (64-bit)

Windows Firewall... disabled

Agnitum Outpost Security... added exceptions for all programs, turned off firewall, turned off anti-leak, suspended protection, turned off self-protect, and stopped process*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have solved my own problem.
Even after disabling every part of the Agnitum Outpost Security package that I could the ddms still wouldn't work, but after I uninstalled Agnitum Outpost the ddms worked just fine.

The problem is with Agnitum Outpost blocking the socket at some low level, perhaps driver or something like that.